# Calculating non-continuous duration period in R

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp

I have a large dataset, with numerous behavioral observations and I am trying to calculate the duration of each individual behaviour **daily**.

Here's a sample of it for 2022-06-04

```r
library(tidyverse)
data_tibble <- tibble::tribble(
  ~bird_ID,       ~longitude,        ~latitude,        ~date, ~Position_Burst_ID,            ~timestamp,  ~longitude_mean,   ~latitude_mean,            ~Dist,
  "048T", 58.4836921691895, 68.8644866943359, "2022-06-04",               5121, "2022-06-04 09:49:38", 58.4966227901897, 68.8623445334237, 571.205432837044,
  "048T", 58.4836730957031, 68.8645324707031, "2022-06-04",               5122, "2022-06-04 10:19:43", 58.4966227901897, 68.8623445334237, 574.044222782275,
  "048T", 58.4962844848633, 68.8621215820312, "2022-06-04",               5123, "2022-06-04 10:49:36", 58.4966227901897, 68.8623445334237, 28.2914837022366,
  "048T", 58.4961318969727, 68.8620452880859, "2022-06-04",               5124, "2022-06-04 11:19:44", 58.4966227901897, 68.8623445334237, 38.7040772369604,
  "048T", 58.4965591430664,  68.862174987793, "2022-06-04",               5125, "2022-06-04 11:49:37", 58.4966227901897, 68.8623445334237, 19.0458862694959,
  "048T", 58.4965972900391, 68.8622360229492, "2022-06-04",               5126, "2022-06-04 12:19:48", 58.4966227901897, 68.8623445334237, 12.1226274623415,
  "048T", 58.4966316223145,  68.862419128418, "2022-06-04",               5127, "2022-06-04 12:49:39", 58.4966227901897, 68.8623445334237, 8.31144228341025,
  "048T", 58.4971313476562, 68.8621292114258, "2022-06-04",               5128, "2022-06-04 13:19:39", 58.4966227901897, 68.8623445334237,  31.485137709381,
  "048T",  58.494312286377, 68.8651657104492, "2022-06-04",               5129, "2022-06-04 13:49:41", 58.4966227901897, 68.8623445334237,  327.46020021598
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

My sample code:

```r
data_tibble$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(data_tibble$timestamp) #to convert it to POSIXct 

nest_duration_perday <- data_tibble %>%
  filter(Dist <= 30) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(duration = max(timestamp) - min(timestamp))
```

The problem is that these periods are not continuous. For example, that individual meets the *nesting* behaviour criteria, when they stay in a 30m radius. Because they start and end the day real close to the nest, that's their `max(timestamp)` and `min(timestamp`, the results have this individual nesting for almost 23hrs.

[image: Distance from the nest/Time]

Any idea on how to approach this?

This is the output I get for 2022-06-04:

```r
outpout
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   date       duration      
#>   <chr>      <drtn>        
#> 1 2022-06-04 23.00056 hours
```

But I want to calculate the duration of the low points in the graph, so it should be closer to 9hrs, not 23hrs.

Edit1: I forgot to mention that I want to calculate that on a daily basis.

Edit2: I added a semi desirable output.

Comment: Can you edit the question and a desired output?

Comment: Kinda difficult to help when the sample only contain one date with no dist over 30. Are you able to upload the data with at least three dates and better sample of Dist?

Comment: @Tom, I changed the given sample data.

Comment: I uploaded different timestamps, the data are relatively big so I can't upload whole days.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my **new** approach with base function and for loop

First i identify nesting periods and i discriminate nesting session.
Then for each birds, i loop through nesting session to sum the time spent and i save the results for all birds in tab2.

If the nesting session concern only one row, i count NA time for it

Let me know if its working.

```
data_tibble$nesting <- ifelse(test = data_tibble$Dist < 30, "yes", "no")

data_tibble$session <- 0

for (i in 2:nrow(data_tibble)){
    if(data_tibble[i,10]==data_tibble[i-1,10]){
    data_tibble[i,11] <- data_tibble[i-1,11]   
 
}else{data_tibble[i,11] <- data_tibble[i-1,11]+1}}

data_nest <- data_tibble[data_tibble$Dist<30,]

tab1 <- data_nest[1,] 
tab1$time_session <- NA 
tab2 <- tab1

for(i in unique(data_nest$bird_ID)){

     data_nest2 <- data_nest[data_nest$bird_ID==i,]   
     data_nest2$time_session <- NA

     for(j in unique(data_nest2$session)){
    
    data_nest3 <- data_nest2[data_nest2$session==j,]
    tab3 <- data_nest3[1,]
    
      if(nrow(data_nest3)==1){
          
        tab3$time_session <- NA

      }else if (nrow(data_nest3)>=2){
          
          for (k in 2:nrow(data_nest3)){
            
            data_nest3[k,12] <- difftime(as.character(data_nest3[k,6]),as.character(data_nest[k-1,6]))
            tab3$time_session <- sum(na.omit(data_nest3$time_session))
            
          }
          
      }else{NULL}
            
    tab1 <- rbind(tab1,tab3)

    }

    tab2 <- rbind(tab2,tab1)    
 }


tab2 <- tab2[!duplicated(tab2),]
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply! I realized that I forgot to mention that I wanted that duration to be daily. I do not want the total duration of the nesting, I want the daily total duration.

Comment: You mean that you want to calculate the duration when "Dist" is < 30m ?

Comment: Yes, in a daily basis. So for example: 
`2022-06-04, 9 hrs`, `2022-06-07, 6hrs`.

Comment: With your new data set i understand your point. However, what is your decision when the birds "nests" (dist <30) for one row ? Ex: row 3.

Comment: To be honest, not considering them, because there is always the possibility of our GPS-tracker's inaccuracy (50m radius). For example in the new data I provided the 5th row would still count in the nesting duration.

Comment: the new loops should work

Comment: hey thanks for all the effort, honestly. I am trying and whenever I get results I will let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251031/discussion-between-helianthus-and-beeflight31).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, we should have sample data with multiple dates and not only for `2022-06-04`

```
library(tidyverse)

data_tibble %>% 
  type_convert() %>%  
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(
    duration = sum(if_else(Dist <= 30, lead(timestamp) - timestamp, 0))
  ) 

# A tibble: 1 × 2
  date       duration     
  <date>     <drtn>       
1 2022-06-04 120.1667 mins
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up using a simpler approach than I thought, and I just flagged each timestamp depending on its distance from the nest, by creating a `nesting` column, calculated the duration of the intervals, grouped by date and summarized according to the `nesting` value.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# Creating a new column based on the distance from the nest #
data_tibble <- data_tibble %>%
  mutate(nesting = ifelse(Dist <= 100, "yes", "no"))

# Calculating the interval with the previous timestamp in hours #
data_tibble <- data_tibble %>%
  mutate(interval = c(NA, diff(as.numeric(timestamp))/3600))
#> Warning in diff(as.numeric(timestamp)): NAs introduced by coercion

# Summarized by date to get the daily results, and then grouped by nesting #
nest_duration <- data_tibble %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(nesting_duration = sum(interval[nesting == "yes"]),
            offnest_duration = sum(interval[nesting == "no"], na.rm = T))

print(nest_duration)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   date       nesting_duration offnest_duration
#>   <chr>                 <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 2022-06-04             3.00             1.00
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I increased the distance threshold based on the rest of the data set, but it doesn't really interfere with anything.